# Are there any add-ons which add thesaurus functionality to search

Tags: search

I have a project where whenever we perform a search we would like to check for synonyms and translations and search for them at the same time. For example a search for "mill stone" will also search for "millstone" and "meule".

I'm guessing that this would be impossible with the native search module but is it something that could be achieved with Solspace Super Search or Low Search?

Comment: My first thought would be to look at manipulating a Tag addon...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super Search has [fuzzy searching](http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/fuzzy_searching/), which basically means plural/singular matching, "sounds like" matching and some spelling matching. However, as far as I know, this is limited to English only.

A solution that would work for both Low Search and Super Search, is to have a hidden field with searchable keywords per entry, which you'd have to populate manually. More work, but more control, too.

If that doesn't work, you might need to go away from EE for the search itself, and use something like a Google custom search.